# Emacs - "Uncompression program 'gzip' not found" when trying to open Info files

Tags: windows, emacs, gzip, emacs24

I'm am completely new to Emacs, so this may be a very naive question but I can't seem to find anything on this.

The basic issue seems to be that I can't open any of the "Info" topics.

The error that I get when I try to open any of them is:

```
Uncompression program 'gzip' not found
```

I have installed Gzip for Windows ([here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm)), but that did not fix the issue.

I have tried this on both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 machines. I am using Emacs 24.3 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601), although I've also tried Emacs 24.4.50.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) from [here](http://semantic.supelec.fr/popineau/programming-emacs.html#sec-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the gzip library isn't in the path that Emacs uses.

Third-party builds of Emacs are difficult to support, and largely unnecessary today. There are now [official binary releases of Emacs for Windows](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) that should bundle everything you need. I've had plenty of success using these releases on Windows 7.

Download the latest zip (currently `emacs-24.4-bin-i686-pc-mingw32.zip`), unzip the file, and run `wbin/runemacs.exe`. That version should fully support info.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that I was using one of the official versions (the first one I listed in the OP), but I must have misread. Working now

Answer (score 1):

Just download a   [gzip.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/?source=typ_redirect) (window version of course)
and let EMACS access it.
Since this will save you some space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [w64 build](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/) contains compressed Elisp sources, while the [official build](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) has them uncompressed. Therefore, if you simply uncompress all sources, it should also work with the w64 version (which contains more libraries).

I did the following in the mingw bash shell (which should also work in Cygwin) in the root folder of Emacs:

> find -name \*.gz -exec gunzip "{}" \;